# How do I stop some of the words from going "inwards"?

Tags: formatting

I just started trying to learn LaTex and have some questions.

If I want to make a new paragraph, or simply just have a blank line between text, what do I use? \, \newline or \bigspace?

I'm also struggling with the structure of my document. The word **Arithmetic** is going inwards a bit. How do I fix that?

Here's my doc:

```
Math: 

\[f(x) = (x+2)^2-9\]

\begin{align*}
    f(x) & = a_2 x^2 + a_1 x + a_0 \\
    & = x^2 +4x -5
\end{align*}
\newline
if equations in text:
\(f(x) = x^2 + 4x -5\) is a function!

\bigskip


\textbf{Arithmetic:}
\newline
$1+1$ = $1+1$ \newline
$5-3$ = $5-3$ \newline
\verb|6 \cdot 4| = $6 \cdot 4 \newline$
\verb|6 \times 4| = $6 \times 4 \newline$
\verb|27 \div 9| = $27 \div 9$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome. The word you look for is probably indenting. Now you can search for the word and how to enable/disable it.

Comment: An input blank line is just two presses of the return key.  It will cause the first line of the next paragraph to be indented, which is what is happening with "Arithmetic".  I suggest that you think of that as a heading on some level of section.  That kind of structuring is provided by most document classes, so the documentation for te class you are using is where you should look.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: After you master \indent and \noindant, try playing with \hangindent.

Comment: FWIW, `parskip` is a useful package if you would prefer paragraphs to be separated by (vertical) skips but with no indenting on the first line.

Comment: you should almost never need to use `\\ ` nor `\newline` in a document, or explicit spacing such as `\bigskip`, such things should be specified at teh document levl not on every line, eg if **Arihmetic** is a heading you can use `\section*{Arithmetic}` which will ensure all such headings get thesame font and spacing which can be specifid in the preamble if the defaults are not suitable.  Just use a blank line to mark  paragraphs, but don't leave a blank line before math displays

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Avoid putting explicit newlines or vertical spaces in your document.

To mark the end of a paragraph just use a blank line so

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.

Red green blue yellow black white orange purple.
Red green blue yellow black white orange purple.
Red green blue yellow black white orange purple.

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

With the start of each paragraph marked by in an indent ("going in") which is the traditional form in typeset material.

If you want paragraphs marked (as is traditional on web pages) with no indent and instead a vertical space, that could be specified using the `parskip` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parskip}

\begin{document}

One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.
One two three four five six seven eight nine ten.

Red green blue yellow black white orange purple.
Red green blue yellow black white orange purple.
Red green blue yellow black white orange purple.

\end{document}
```

Produces

[image]

In either case the heading should use markup denoting a heading such as

`\section*{Arithmetic}`

Headings are not indented in most styles.